# SqlAnywhere, Ruby and macOS Sierra. DBCAPI libraries couldn't be loaded

Tags: ruby, sqlanywhere

Are anyone using Ruby and SAP SQLAnywhere in Web development?

I was using Rails 4 to develop some applications but after upgrading my macOS to Sierra the libraries couldn't be loaded even after sourcing sa_config.sh.
It keeps showing  'DBCAPI libraries couldn't be loaded...' message.
Doing a quick search, it seems that there is no activities for both (Ruby and SQLAnywhere) since 4-5 years ago...

Comment: You may get a response from the sqlanywhere developers on the [sqlanywhere forum](http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/)

Comment: @mark i will try there